# How do I run qmake to install templar?

Tags: qt, qmake, build-error

This is a borderline question but it's a bit programmy so I thought I'd try here instead of Super User. I am trying to install [templar](https://github.com/schulmar/Templar), so I downloaded the source and attempted to run `qmake` to install it. When I do, I get this message:

> Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in Qt: xmlpatterns

I don't have particular interest in learning about the internals of Qt, other than what is needed to compile templar. Is this message telling me that the module can't be found, or that `Qt` doesn't know what to do with it?

And how do I remedy this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Qt distribution wasn't build with the `xmlpatterns` module. You need to [download a new distribution](http://qt-project.org/downloads) from the website. In the worst case you will have to compile it yourself but it isn't quite hard.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same error while building an other project using Ubuntu.

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5xmlpatterns5-dev
```